# Unit tests mocks fails on rest API requests in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

Hi I am new to unit testing and I am digging into mocks and pytest.I am trying to unit test two rest api requests where the GET request checks if an item doesn't exist in the API and if it does not create it with POST request and to create a folder, otherwise if it exists just to create a folder.

I tried to use `Mocker()` and I am stuck on `AttributeError: Mocker` when I try to mock the `GET` request.

This is the code I am trying to test:

```
   client = requests.session()
    # get item by name
    response = client.get(
        f"https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item",
        auth=username, password),
    )

    if (
        response.status_code == 200
        and response.json()["status"]
        == "Item doesn't exist!"
    ):
        logging.info(f"Creating item")
        client.post(
            "https://url.com/rest/item/create?name=test_item",
            auth=username, password),
        )
        # directory creation
        dir_make = "mkdir -p test_item/temperature"
        exec_cmd(dir_make)

    elif response.status_code == 200 and response.json()["status"]=="OK":
        # directory creation
        dir_make = "mkdir -p test_item/temperature"
        exec_cmd(dir_make)
```

And this is the unit test that fails with `AttributeError`:

```
def test_existing_item(requests_mock, monkeypatch):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:
        mock.get("https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item", text="OK")

        resp = requests.get("https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item")
        assert resp.text == "OK"
```

EDIT: Test for item not found and `POST` mock. It seems like it doesn't add coverage to the `else` statement. How can be tested if the item exists and only the folder needs to be added in that case?

EDIT 2: Added `elif` statement instead of `else` and 2 separate tests, still the one `test_existing_items()` doesn't cover the `elif` statement...What am I doing wrong in that case?

```
def test_existing_item(monkeypatch):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock_request:
        mock_request.get(requests_mock.ANY, text="success!")
        resp = requests.get(
            "https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item",
            auth=("mock_username", "mock_password"),
        )
        if resp.status_code == 200 and resp.json()["status"] == "OK":
            dir_make = "mkdir -p test_item/temperature"
            exec_cmd(dir_make)


    encoded_auth = b64encode(b"mock_username:mock_password").decode("ascii")

    assert mock_request.last_request.headers["Authorization"] == f"Basic {encoded_auth}"


def test_post_item(monkeypatch):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock_request:
        mock_request.get(requests_mock.ANY, text="success!")
        resp = requests.get(
            "https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item",
            auth=("mock_username", "mock_password"),
        )

        if resp.status_code == 200 and resp.json()["status"] == "ERROR":
            mock_request.get(requests_mock.ANY, text="success!")
            requests.post(
                "https://url.com/rest/item/create?name=test_item",
                auth=("mock_username", "mock_password"),
            )

        dir_make = "mkdir -p test_item/temperature"
        exec_cmd(dir_make)


    encoded_auth = b64encode(b"mock_username:mock_password").decode("ascii")

    assert mock_request.last_request.headers["Authorization"] == f"Basic {encoded_auth}"
```

I am not familiar with unit testing so any help would be appreciated to unit test this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import requests_mock


def test_existing_item(monkeypatch):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:
        mock.get("https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item", text="OK")

        resp = requests.get("https://url.com/rest/item/info?name=test_item")
        assert resp.text == "OK"
```

Don't pass `requests_mock` as parameter and `pytest` should work fine.

EDIT:

As for your edit:

> It seems like it doesn't add coverage to the else statement. How can be tested if the item exists and only the folder needs to be added in that case?

That would be because your `if` condition is always true, so it never accesses the code below the `else` statement. Your second question is rather unclear to me, but I believe you want to write several tests, one for your `if` statement and one for your `else` statement. As a rule of thumb, if you need conditional logic in your test, you have a problem: either everything should go as you want it to every time you run your tests, either you should abort and have the test fail, as you want your code to have the exact same behavior every time you run it - and your tests as well, by extension.

Comment: @JohnyMostoq It will work just as well if you replace `.get()` calls to `.post()` calls in the code I sent. If that's not enough to test your code, then I'd like to see the tests you run on the code you sent

Comment: @JohnyMostoq I edited my comment. I hope this answered your question

Comment: I did as you suggested, separated into 2 tests and i got the same result for the same piece of code(no coverage, whenever the item exists)... I updated the question with the separated tests and changes of the code. I didn't quite undestood what you meant by "if you need conditional logic in your test, you have a problem", is it a bad practice to have conditions in unit tests?

Comment: @JohnyMostoq I suppose it is a matter of opinion, but I feel like most would call it bad practice. The purpose of a test is to ensure code acts a certain way and returns a certain value. If you have conditional logic, either its behavior or output can change upon several runs even if it's called in the same way every time - which means you need to refactor your code to prevent this - or one condition will never be entered, and so if you want both pieces of code (one for each branch) to be executed, you need to split it into two tests, both modifying the environment accordingly beforehand.

Comment: @JohnyMostoq As for your main issue, do they fail on your machine? And how do you detect coverage?